# Get value of array wih objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, return-value, key-value, javascript-objects

I am using Firebug and when i console log an array, the value am getting is: Array [ ] 
I can see in the right panel of Firebug how the array has items 3 objects, but i cannot reach them. How could i get the values?, here is an image:

[image]

Comment: Iterate through it. This isn't Firebug, by the way.

Comment: Click on the gray arrow at left of `0: Object` or `1: Object`

Comment: As Shahar has stated, you're not using [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/), rather it's browser's console.

Comment: trully sorry i was so confused i didn't realize

Comment: @LcSalazar i did and i can see the values when i click the gray arrow, am trying to get the values like this(without results):
angular.forEach(c, function(cat) { 
console.log('Categorias '); 
console.log(cat); 
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several JavaScript methods for accessing the array:

```
var array = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'world'];

//simple for loop
for(var i in array){
    console.log('array item value: ', array[i]);
}

//forEach loop
array.forEach(function(value){
    console.log('array item value: ', value);
});
```

Your array may have strings, numbers, objects, booleans, etc as each item, once you have access to that item using one of the above methods you can manipulate that item however you'd like.

[Information on forEach loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[Information on for loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

[Information on iterating arrays](http://www.sebarmeli.com/blog/2010/12/06/best-way-to-loop-through-an-array-in-javascript/)

Comment: am doing this, but it just doesn't loop or log anything.

 console.log(c); // this logs Array [ ]
angular.forEach(c, function(cat) {
                console.log('Categorias ');
                console.log(cat);
            });

And also try the way you say:
array.forEach(function(value){
    console.log('array item value: ', value);
}); 

But still nothing logs.

Comment: Can you post the exact code you have that you are trying to use?

Comment: yeah:

function populateUser(u, c, e) {
        // console.log(u);
        console.log(c);
        // console.log(e);
        
        c.forEach(function(value){
            console.log('array item value: ', value);
        });
        
        angular.forEach(c, function(cat) {
                console.log('Categorias ');
                console.log(cat);
 });
}
It's a longer function but it should loop throght the array and add into indexedDB, it's inside an app.factory( function(){});

Comment: If you mean how the array if formed, i made a jsonService factory that gives me the array

Comment: when you call function `populateUser(u, c, e)` is the array being entered in for c?

Comment: here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10154/) with the code you entered in the comment above working, just open your console and look at the logs.  It is working properly.

Comment: C is just an array for categories, e is another array.

Comment: Do you see the wokring jsFiddle example above? Does your code look like the jsFiddle code?

Comment: I implemented and used the loops you first posted  and also fix the one already have and works( which is inside a controller ), but i don't know why doesn't work inside the function populateUsers(). I don't know if it's worth to mention am using Dexie.js and am using the code to loop inside the array inside de function populateUsers(which is inside a service.js and in a factory).

Comment: Yeah man I am just missing too much context here sorry, I don't know that I can be much more help without a complete/thorough example of what you are doing.

Comment: yeah i see the jsFiddle code and when i implemented the loops was almost like you did

Comment: can you put a console log right after `var categories = jsonService.getjson( id, path, aK).then(function(d) {` for d and let me know what the value of d is?

Comment: also I would use angular $http service not jQuery's $.get() methods

Comment: here i got the photo of the console.log you ask:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zdccttxetmq42f9/stack02.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Your promise is returning correctly.  What does the function jsonService.getjson( id, path, aK) look like?

Comment: the value of d is:
Object { categories: Array[3] }   
so i could instead of making a new array as am seeing now i could just send the whole value to the function, right?

Comment: Yes I would do that, when you use jQuery to make your ajax call you are no longer in the Angular digest cycle which will not keep $scope up to date.  Try using straight d.categories instead of setting it equal to a variable.  Let me know if that works

Comment: was my first approach to kind of routing the json calls with id path and key, and i was about to ask the reason of the choice between get and http and now i know why hehe, thanks, am checking right now

Comment: hi, sorry to bother again but  as i can't find the issue that is causing me the same Array [ ], i log this and i can see that at the end the value does not remain in the array. I can't save them outside the scope of the jsonService: http://hastebin.com/ukaduvocof.coffee

Comment: I don't understand what you just said

Comment: sorry, i understood the issue, that was i wasn't pointing in the right array, but now i can't figure out why i cannot save the value that was generated inside the var categories = jsonService function outside the function, i made the log and show as an empty array.